# CTypes, Python Callback, and FORTRAN

Tags: python-3.x, callback, fortran, ctypes

I am new to Python (and FORTRAN as well) but happen to be writing an interface for a FORTRAN solver which I will call from my Python code. I am using Python 3 right now and trying to use ctypes to write the interface. Since the solver SUBROUTINE has around 40 parameters, I will show my question using a simple example in FORTRAN and Python.

First, consider the main FORTRAN subroutine in ex3_func.f

```
subroutine ex3_func (PP,num,dim,funptrObjFun)

        implicit none

        integer, intent(in) :: num, dim

        real(8), intent(inout) :: PP(num,dim)

        external funptrObjFun

        PP = (PP+PP)*3.0

        call funptrObjFun(PP,num,dim)

        return

    end subroutine
```

Compiling this using: $> gfortran -c ex3_func.f 
gives no problem at all.

I also have a c interface to this subroutine, as a module in ex3_cfunc.f

```
module cwrapper_ex3cfunc

    use iso_c_binding, only: c_int, c_double, c_funptr

    implicit none 

    contains

    subroutine ex3_cfunc(PP, num, dim, ptrfunObjFun) bind(c)

        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: num, dim

        real(c_double), intent(inout) :: PP(num,dim)

        type(c_funptr), intent(inout) :: ptrfunObjFun

        call ex3_func(PP,num,dim,ptrfunObjFun)

        return
    end subroutine

end module
```

Compiling this using: $> gfortran -c ex3_cfunc.f
gives no problems as well.

Finally, I run: $> gfortran -shared -O2 ex3_func.o ex3_cfunc.o -o lib_ex3func.so -fPIC

which gives no problems and generates the file lib_ex3func.so

Before moving to the Python code, note that funptrObjFunc (a pointer to a function) will call a Python function called writetomatrix() -- see below-- in the main Python program.

Here is the Python code that will call this FORTRAN lib.

```
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

num=3
dim=4

AA = ((ct.c_double *dim) *num)
print(type(AA))
print(AA)
XX = AA()

<class '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'>
<class '__main__.c_double_Array_4_Array_3'>

#Fill XX with anything:
for i in range(0,num):
    for j in range(0,dim):
        XX[i][j]= (i+1)*(j+1)

def writetomatrix (FF,num,dim):
    print("num x dim : ",num[0],dim[0])
    print(FF)
    print(np.shape(FF),'\n')

    #Write to an element
    FF[2][3]=99.0
    print(np.ctypeslib.as_array(FF))

ptrfunc = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None,AA,ct.POINTER(ct.c_int),ct.POINTER(ct.c_int))

FORTRAN = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary('lib_ex3func.so')

#Execution!
FORTRAN.ex3_cfunc(XX,ct.byref(ct.c_int(num)),ct.byref(ct.c_int(dim)),ptrfunc(writetomatrix))

#output
num x dim :  3 4
<__main__.c_double_Array_4_Array_3 object at 0x106de1840>
(3, 4) 

[[  2.16962762e-314   1.97626258e-323   6.95321987e-310   2.16813588e-314]
 [  6.95321987e-310   6.95321987e-310   6.95321987e-310   6.95321987e-310]
 [  6.95321987e-310   2.16918622e-314   2.12199579e-314   9.90000000e+001]]

# As you can see (above) writetomatrix can't see nor access the original XX.       
# It prints garbage and the 99.0 value in the last element! The FORTRAN   
# procedure, however, does what it's suppoosed to do, and the answer below is 
# correct. My question is how writetomatrix can access XX and modify it's 
# elements?

ZZ=np.ctypeslib.as_array(XX)
ZZ

array([[  6.,  12.,  18.,  24.],
       [ 12.,  24.,  36.,  48.],
       [ 18.,  36.,  54.,  72.]])
```

My question and my problem is that I need to access the elements of XX and modify the elements of XX from writetomatrix(). I couldn't figure out how to do it. It is the Python code, the FORTRAN code, or both?! Will appreciate your help and explanation :)

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Don't use an array type in the argument types. Arrays are passed as pointers, and ctypes will try to initialize the array literally from the pointer address (and then some) on the stack. Instead use `ptrfunc = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.POINTER(ct.c_double), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int))`. Then in `writetomatrix` cast this pointer to the desired array using `XX = ct.POINTER((ct.c_double * dim[0]) * num[0]).from_buffer(FF)[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, indeed this worked :) Very much appreciated eryksun!

Comment: May I ask if you know of a fast way to copy numpy arrays elements into the ctype array -- it seems that I will have to rely on double loops to fill XX inside writetomatrix(). This might not be the best option I guess for large vectors and matrices. Thanks again anyways.

Comment: Don't copy at all. Say you have a numpy array `x`, since you haven't defined the function pointer's `argtypes`, you can simply pass the `c_void_p` pointer `x.ctypes`. The pointer is actually `x.ctypes._as_parameter_` property. `_as_parameter_` is a hook that ctypes checks for on arguments.

Comment: I recommend setting `argtypes`, in which you can use a type that defines `from_param` to convert a numpy array automatically. The following creates such a type that allows passing any `float64` Fortran-contiguous array: `f8_f = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, flags='F')`. Set this in the prototype as follows: `FORTRAN.ex3_cfun.argtypes = (f8_f, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int), ptrfunc)`. Now you can directly pass an array that matches that type.

Comment: On an unrelated note, just as an FYI, if a function uses a `ptrfunc` again some time after it returns, you *must* store the callback somewhere (e.g. in a global, a list, a class instance, etc) to prevent it from being deallocated. If the library calls a deallocated callback the result is undefined and may be a puzzling bug depending on what gets executed.

Comment: OK :) it took me some time to read and get all this. Very valuable information indeed and I don't think I would have found them clear in this way. The _as_parameter_ works perfectly and i get it. The f8_f part

Comment: Sorry: I got cut my the limit time. First time user here! any Ways: Thank you again for your time. The documentation out there is poor on these issues.

Comment: The _as_parameter_ works perfectly and I get it. 

The f8_f, I didn't understand what should I pass as the first parameter in:
FORTRAN.ex3_cfunc(??,all other parameters).

Comment: The type create by `ndpointer` implements the ctypes `from_param` hook. For a passed parameter, the job of the `from_param` method of the corresponding type in `argtypes` is to return either a ctypes object, an object with `_as_parameter_` property, or a basic Python object that ctypes can convert such as a string or integer. The `ndpointer` type `from_param` checks that the argument is an array that matches the required type and, if so, returns its `ctypes` attribute. You pass a numpy array -- in the case of the `f8_f` type it has to be a `float64` array created with `order='F'`.

Comment: `ifort` (2021.3.0, from One Api) gives, on `call ex3_func(PP,num,dim,ptrfunObjFun)` a : "When a dummy argument is a subroutine, the corresponding actual argument must also be a subroutine"