# Passing a generic procedure to a function as actual argument

Tags: fortran

I am attempting to pass a generic procedure as an actual argument to a function:

```
module mymod
implicit none

interface func
  module procedure :: func1
  module procedure :: func2
endinterface func

contains

real function func1(x)
  real,intent(in) :: x
  func1 = 2*x
endfunction func1

real function func2(x,y)
  real,intent(in) :: x
  real,intent(in) :: y
  func2 = 2*x + 3*y
endfunction func2

real function func3(func,x,y)
  interface
    real function func(x,y)
      real,intent(in) :: x
      real,intent(in) :: y
    endfunction func
  endinterface
  real,intent(in) :: x
  real,intent(in) :: y
  func3 = func(x,y)
endfunction func3

endmodule mymod

program myprogram
use mymod
implicit none
write(*,*)func3(func,2.,3.)
endprogram myprogram
```

gfortran 6.2.0 notes that I cannot do this:

```
test.f90:43:16:

 write(*,*)func3(func,2.,3.)
                1
Error: GENERIC procedure ‘func’ is not allowed as an actual argument at (1)
```

Similarly, with ifort 17:

```
test.f90(39): error #8164: A generic interface name shall not be used as an actual argument.   [FUNC]
write(*,*)func3(func,2.,3.)
----------------^
test.f90(39): error #6637: When a dummy argument is a function, the corresponding actual argument must also be a function.   [FUNC]
write(*,*)func3(func,2.,3.)
----------------^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

I am reading through the 2008 Standard section on generic interfaces and I cannot find such restriction. I also cannot think of a reason why the compiler would not be able to resolve the generic interface at compile-time. My gut is telling me that this should be doable, but I may not have the right approach. Do you know of a standard-compliant way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not allowed. Actually, you cannot even pass generic INTRINSIC functions as dummy arguments.

A standard compliant way is to use the right specific functions directly. With INTRINSIC functions you sometimes must write a wrapper for the right kind, when the specific doesn't have a standard name.

For example:

```
  call integrate(derf,0.,1.)

  contains
    function derf(x)
      real(dbl) :: derf
      real(dbl), intent(in) :: x
      derf = erf(x)
    end function
  end
```

is necessary if you want to pass the double precision real (or any other) version of `erf()` because there is no specific function available.

Comment: I will comment that using specific functions will become nonstandard in Fortran 2015. At that point there will be no way to pass an intrinsic function as a procedure argument and will have to use the wrapper method to stay standards-compliant. (I also note that no new specific names for intrinsics have been added since Fortran 95.)

Comment: Why was this working then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167488/ctypes-python-callback-and-fortran ? Does becoming non standard always means illegal compiler-wise ?

Comment: @Olorin Please be specific. Why was working what exactly?

Answer (score 3):

The Fortran standard doesn't allow one to pass generic procedures as arguments. In order to pass intrinsic functions/subroutines one must resort to user-defined wrapper procedures.

```
module mymod

    ! Explicit typing only
    implicit none

    ! Declare procedure interface
    interface
       function my_func(x, y) result (return_value)
         real, intent(in) :: x, y
         real             :: return_value
       end function my_func
    end interface

contains

    function func1(x) result (return_value)
       real,intent(in) :: x
       real            :: return_value

       return_value = 2*x

    end function func1

    function func2(x, y) result (return_value)
       real, intent(in) :: x, y
       real             :: return_value

       return_value = 2*x + 3*y

    end function func2

    function func3(user_defined_func, x, y) result (return_value)
       procedure(my_func)  :: user_defined_func
       real, intent(in)    :: x, y
       real                :: return_value

       return_value = user_defined_func(x,y)

    end function func3

end module mymod

program main

    use ISO_Fortran_env, only: &
       stdout => OUTPUT_UNIT, &
       compiler_version, &
       compiler_options

    use mymod

    ! Explicit typing only
    implicit none

    write (stdout, *) func3(func2, 2.0, 3.0)
    write (stdout, *) func3(foo, 2.0, 3.0)
    write (stdout, *) func3(my_atan2, 2.0, 3.0)

    print '(/4a/)', &
    ' This file was compiled using ', compiler_version(), &
    ' using the options ', compiler_options()

contains

    ! A user defined function
    function foo(x, y) result (return_value)
       real, intent(in) :: x, y
       real             :: return_value

       return_value = 42

    end function foo

    ! A wrapper function to invoke the intrinsic atan2
    function my_atan2(x, y) result (return_value)
       real, intent(in) :: x, y
       real             :: return_value

       return_value = atan2(x,y)

    end function my_atan2

end program main
```

yields

```
gfortran -std=f2008ts -o main.exe  mymod.f90 main.f90
./main.exe
   13.0000000    
   42.0000000    
  0.588002622    

 This file was compiled using GCC version 6.1.1 20160802 using the options -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=f2008ts
```