# Why does intrinsic function exp fail to work when passed as an argument in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have in a module where the function *gauss_int* that takes an implicit function (argument *F*) and two reals (*aa* and *bb*) as arguments. *gauss_int* approximates the integral of the implicit function between *aa* and *bb* that are the limits of integration. *gauss_int* is called by the main program which passes the intrinsic function *exp* for integration.

The result is not what I would expect, since the *exp* passed as an argument produces incorrect results (see *F-* and *F+* in the output). Giving 0 and 1 as the integration limits, I would expect the final result to be 1.7178... but I get 0 as the approximate value of the integral. As can be seen from the output, the value of *F-* is not equal to *exp(yy1-yy2)* though it should be. Other values for *aa* and *bb*  also give odd results
, e.g. -2 and 3 respectively give *F-*=Infinity and *F+*=1.0...

Below the module and the main program, which I have in separate files. I am using GNU Fortran 6.3.0 on OSX.

EDIT:
I added a wrapper to the module, and the main program calls the wrapper function *myexp* instead of the implicit *exp*. Also removed the intrinsic functions *sin* and *exp* in the declaration of the main program. Now the program works fine. Good advice at [Passing a generic procedure to a function as actual argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643775/passing-a-generic-procedure-to-a-function-as-actual-argument)

```
module Gaussintegrationformula
 !This module contains a function for the
 !Gauss integration formula

  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: rk16=16
  integer,parameter :: ik16=16


   contains

    function gauss_int(F,aa,bb)
      implicit none
      real(kind=rk16) :: gauss_int
      real(kind=rk16),intent(in) :: aa,bb !lower and upper bound
      real, external :: F !function to be integrated
      real(kind=rk16) :: xx,yy1,yy2,zz,two,three !intermediate      variables
      two=2
      three=3
      xx=(bb-aa)/two
      yy1=(aa+bb)/two
      yy2=(bb-aa)/(two*sqrt(three))
      zz=F(yy1-yy2)+F(yy1+yy2)   
      gauss_int=xx*zz

      print *, 'xx',xx
      print *, 'yy1',yy1
      print *, 'yy2',yy2
      print *, 'F-', F(yy1-yy2)
      print *, 'F+', F(yy1+yy2)
      print *, 'exp(yy1-yy2)', exp(yy1-yy2)
      return
    end function gauss_int

   !EDIT, ADDED WRAPPER
   !This is a wrapper that calls the specific function
   !'exp' that has kind 'real 16'
   !instead of standard single precision
   function myexp(xx)
     implicit none
     real(kind=rk16) :: myexp
     real(kind=rk16) :: xx
     myexp=exp(xx)
   end function myexp


  end module Gaussintegrationformula


 program Gaussintegration
  !This program uses the Gauss integration formula
  !in module ' Gaussintegrationformula' to calculate
  !integrals

   use  Gaussintegrationformula
   implicit none
   real(kind=rk16) :: mm,nn,ans
   integer :: ios

   print *
   print *, 'This program calculates the integral of function f(x) using Gauss'' integration formula'
   write(6,'(a)',advance='no') 'Give integration bounds, first lower    then upper, separated by a comma: '
   read(5,*,iostat=ios) mm,nn

   !validate input
   if (ios/=0) then
   print *, '***Error in reading the integration bounds. The program teminates.***'
   stop
   end if

   !calculate integral
   ans=gauss_int(myexp,mm,nn) !change the first argument to a different    function as desired, and add a new wrapper to the module
   print *, 'The approximate value of the integral is ',ans


  end program Gaussintegration
```

Comment: The linked question is appropriate because: you are passing the _specific_ function `exp` (which accepts default real) rather than the _generic_ `exp`.

Comment: Thank you francescalus. I got the program working with the help of a wrapper in the module. Upvoted the accepted answer at the linked topic.

Comment: I hope you also fixed the line `zz=F(yy1-yy2)+F(yy1-yy2)`.

Comment: I did, also noticed my mistake there with the signs.